# Meteor: set the starting page (location)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

How do you get a Meteor app to start up on a particular page?  If you don't control this, then the browser remembers where you were in the app when you last closed the app, and it tries to load that old location.  Which is fine, if that's what you want, but if not, then what do you do?

Using iron-router in my app, this used to work:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

  Router.go('/');

});
```

Now this throws an error in Router.js, complaining that self._location is undefined.  It's as if the call to Router.go() is happening too soon now.  Is there a way to know when Router is ready for a go() call?  Or a way to introduce a delay here?

**_________________EDIT_________________**

In an attempt to solve this, I have reduced everything down to the essentials.  Here's all my code, 2 files in total:

newPL.js:

```
Router.configure({

  layoutTemplate: 'layout'

});



Router.map(function () {

   this.route('home', {

     path: '/',

  });

  this.route('main', {

    path: '/main',

  });

});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {

     Router.go('home');

    });
}
```

and newPL.html:

```
<head>
  <title>newPL</title>
</head>

<template name='layout'>

    <div>
      {{> yield}}
    </div>

</template>

<template name='home'>

    <div>

      Welcome to Planet Lingo!

    <a href='/main'>GO</a>

    </div>

</template>

<template name='main'>

    <div>

    <h1>Main</h1>

    </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in iron-router. Iron router does a Meteor.defer around router.start see: [Iron-router source](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/89949227f251664888ffd90cb09268aec6e20da0/lib/client/router.js) line 34

You can work around this by using Meteor.defer yourself

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.defer(function () {Router.go('home');});
});
```

This works fine as your defer gets put below the one thats created by iron-router

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the exact same result. That's the way I normally use Router.go(), but I changed it above to simplify the example.  (Router.go() actually does work with a literal path like "/" or "/home" or whatever.)  When it's working, that is.  Which for me, is all the time, except during this crucial start-up sequence.

Comment: @MichaelMcC I tried it on one of my applications and I don't get a error.
Can you maybe share some of your router config code?

Comment: Edited the question to include all my code, which now raises an even more fundamental error (????).

Comment: Fixed the new error -- now I'm back to the old one (Can't read property set of undefined, self._location is router.js is undefined)

Comment: @MichaelMcC found the cause of your problem and updated my answer

Comment: That did it!!  I can't thank you enough.  I've been beating my head against the wall on this one, researching everything I could about the startup function in meteor but I was getting nowhere.  Meteor.defer() is new to me.  Now to look it up ... (EDIT) 'defer' doesn't appear in the Meteor docs at all!  WTF??

Comment: @MichaelMcC Np, Im not quite sure why Meteor.defer is undocumented.
Basicly its a setImmediate see
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/b5cd66dedd014a8df7990f9160284c78103ef955/packages/meteor/timers.js line 42

And https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/d477c8d03bb078f7e8e85dbe4b51db7ae5689573/packages/meteor/setimmediate.js

For the actual setImmediate implementation.

Nicholas C Zakas wrote a good case why setImmediate is handy: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/09/the-case-for-setimmediate/ 

It basicly is a setTimeout(func, 0);  but faster